# find all connected pixels on an image - javascript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, image, image-processing

I am trying to build a simple OCR system (if there is such a thing!)

I have a successful working model (90% recognition - which I call success :-P) for single characters - I am now trying to make it recognise multiple characters.

What I want to do is find all connected pixels (this system is designed for none joined up writing only)

so if I read across a 1 pixel high line i find a 'black' pixel - how would I then find every connected pixel - efficiently :-P

I could brute force it by literally looking at the pixel above, below, right and left and then looking at each of those pixels in the same manner but I am assuming there is a better methodology.

Or is it better to add every pixel to a matrix and then do comparisons on it then?

I basically want to output a multi dimensional array along the lines of:

```
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
```

Which would be a capital `I`

Javascript is what it is written in, but if someone has the method in PHP I should be able to convert (unless it has multiple libraries needed!)

Hope that is clear - any further info please ask in comments.

Comment: Have a look at [Connected Component Labeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_labeling).

Comment: thanks beaker - that is what I was looking for - add it as an answer (maybe some padding just so if someone else finds the question it looks like a more complete answer) and I will accept